# WiFi symbol missing, 16.04, internet works, all wifi networks available in system settings

Tags: 16.04, wireless

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Brand new to ubuntu, not confident using terminal, but wish to be.

Comment: please post a screen shot of the issue.

Comment: If you reboot, does the network icon reappear?

Comment: yes.  shows wireless connection most of the time but randomly changes back to a wired icon with with internet still working normally

Comment: sometimes it doesnt show an icon at all, but stays connected

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/1585886), you can restart "nm-applet" in command prompt.  No need to reboot or even restart network service.